Проблема с подключением к MySQL: действительный пароль, но ошибка TLS/SSL: неправильный номер версии
Я столкнулся с проблемой при попытке подключиться к MySQL с помощью Hydra в Kali Linux. Несмотря на успешный поиск действующего пароля, я получаю сообщение об ошибке «ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: wrong version number» при попытке получить доступ к серверу MySQL с использованием предоставленных учетных данных. Я относительно новичок в Kali Linux и занимаюсь устранением неполадок в этой среде. Мы будем очень признательны за любые идеи или рекомендации по устранению этой ошибки SSL/TLS.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык
